# Whats best suited in the below scenario (Interface ? Abstract ? Inheritance)

Tags: apex, interface

I have two classes. They both contain a method that has almost the same logic. But the methods differ in a number of parameters.

I want to keep a common method in the base class and use it in several other classes. What can I use abstract, virtual, inheritance?

```
private List<SObject> createRecords(int a,String b){

}

private List<SObject> createRecords(int a){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, either would probably work.

Abstract classes can contain virtual methods, but not the other way around (i.e. virtual classes cannot contain abstract methods).

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated (i.e. you need to instantiate a child class that extends the abstract class), and abstract methods must be implemented by the child class.

Virtual methods can provide a default implementation (but can still be overridden by the child class).

The approach that I would take in this general case would be to make the class with the method with more parameters the "parent" class, and have the "child" class provide a safe default for the missing parameter. The method itself would be declared as `virtual` (because you seem to want to have common behavior among all your classes). It's easier to code for a situation where there's missing data compared to trying to code for having extra data. This, to me, is the more important distinction.

A brief example:

```java
public virtual class ParentClass{
    // non-static member variables are inherited by children if they're
    //   "public" or "protected"
    public Account myAccount;

    virtual public void createRecord(Integer int, String str){
        // Set the fields that don't depend on the second parameter
        // i.e. do the work common to all calls here
        myAccount = new Account(
            Name = 'Prospect - ' + DateTime.now()
        );

        // Everything that is dependent upon the second parameter should be
        //   cordoned off into its own block
        if(String.isNotBlank(str)){
            myAccount.Fax = '555-555-5555';
            myAccount.Description = str;
        }
    }
}

public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{
    public void createRecord(Integer int){
        // The "super" keyword is only used when a child method overrides a
        //   parent method (the method signatures must match).
        // It's a way to resolve ambiguity.
        // In this case, we can just call the method directly
        createRecord(int, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The single-parameter method could be contained in the parent class (and then overridden in child classes, if need be). You haven't given enough context to determine if there's a reason to put a method into the child class.